# Firestore: List subcollections of a document using python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible list subcollections of a document using python?
It seems that google documentation is discordant

Here they say that get collections method is not available in the Python client library:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#python_6

Here they say that class collections() list subcollections:

https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html

So I try something like:

```
collnameref = db.collection(collname)
docs = collnameref.stream()
for doc in docs:
    print (doc.collections())
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: *"But it doesn't work for me"* - please edit the question with the code that isn't working the way you expect, along with an explanation of what it's actually doing instead.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right. This is missing from the documentation:

```
collnameref = db.collection(collname)
docs = collnameref.stream()
for doc in docs:
    # List subcollections in each doc
    for collection_ref in doc.reference.collections():
        print(collection_ref.parent.path + collection_ref.id)
```

Comment: Thanks Juan! Can we assume this will also soon be addressed in the documentation? ;-)

Comment: We're on it :-)