# List subcollections in a document using python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So basically what my requirement is: I have many collections in a Firestore. These collections have 2 different type of subcollections inside a document. So depending on the type of recollections, I have to run a particular code (if the subcollection has 'alert' then I have to run one code, if it has 'data' I have to run another). so I am trying to generalise the code. I am able to get details up to document, but i am not able to list subcollections inside document. How can i do this?

Please check the below code

```
documents_list=[]
result = db.collection('Maping').get()
for doc in result:
    documents_list.append(doc.id)

for docs in documents_list:
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
    collection_list = []
    refids = db.collection(u'Maping').document(docs).get().to_dict()
    for doc in refids:
        collection_list.append(doc)
        print (collection_list)
```

Firebase documentation has no details for subcollections using python.

Comment: We recently updated the docs with an example, see [List subcollections of a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#python_6).

Comment: Also see: [Firestore: List subcollections of a document using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62203845/firestore-list-subcollections-of-a-document-using-python)